# invalid operands of types - c++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a class named ThreeDigits on c++ code. I overloaded the + operand, this way:

```
ThreeDigits* ThreeDigits::operator+(const ThreeDigits &number) const

{
   double result= getNumber()+number.getNumber();
   ThreeDigits* new_result=new ThreeDigits(result);
   return new_result;
}
```

but when I write on the main function:

```
    ThreeDigits* first=new ThreeDigits(2.55998);
    ThreeDigits* second=new ThreeDigits(5.666542);
    ThreeDigits* result=first+second;
```

I get the following compilation error: 
invalid operands of types ThreeDigits* and ThreeDigits* to binary operator+

Can you tell me what is the problem? thanks

Comment: You need to unlearn `new`.

Comment: what about : ThreeDigits* result=(*first)+(*second);

Comment: ...and after unlearning `new`, start learning how to `accept` answers.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "accept" answers?

Comment: @Kerrek: Fourth time in past hour or so in here and I see 0% accepted rate on an OP, I don't know whats happening :)

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to know how to accept answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to sum *pointers to objects* instead of the objects themselves. To invoke the overloaded operator you must call it on objects, thus dereferencing the pointers.

By the way, creating all those objects with `new` a terrible way to do C++; in C++, unlike Java/C#, you should use `new` only when you have to, and allocate all the rest on the stack. Having the `operator+` return a pointer to a newly created object is an abomination.

The C++ way of writing your code would be:

```
ThreeDigits ThreeDigits::operator+(const ThreeDigits &number) const
{
   return ThreeDigits(getNumber()+number.getNumber()); // construct a temporary and return it
}

// ...

ThreeDigits first(2.55998);
ThreeDigits second(5.666542);
ThreeDigits result=first+second;
```

By the way, the usual way of overloading arithmetic operators is first overloading the assigning versions (+=, -=, ...) and then build the "normal" version over them. For more info about operator overloading see the [operator overloading FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: Just curious, but why did you use `()`-style initialization in the first two lines and `=`-style initialization in the last line?

Comment: @Rob: I don't really know... :) Maybe because it remained from the copy-paste of the original code, maybe because it felt more "natural" at the moment to have an expression like `x=y+z`.

Answer (score 3):

To use your operator as written, you'd need to write: `ThreeDigits* result=*first+*second;` in order to dereference the pointers.

However, your operator has at least two problems: One, it violates the principle of least surprise in that canonically `operator+` returns by value. Second, it returns a pointer to new memory that will most likely be leaked in a wide variety of cases unless care is taken.

It looks like you may come from a Java background where everything is reference counted. Instead, the idiomatic C++ implementation would look like this:

```
ThreeDigits ThreeDigits::operator+(const ThreeDigits &number) const
{
   double result= getNumber()+number.getNumber();
   return ThreeDigits(result);
}
```

And used:

```
ThreeDigits first(2.55998);
ThreeDigits second(5.666542);
ThreeDigits result = first+second;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not dereferencing the pointers. Try this:

```
ThreeDigits* result = *first + *second;
```

Comment: That makes it compile, but only digs the problem deeper… there simply should be no pointers in this code.

Answer (score 1):

Your operator accept two ThreeDigits references and returns a ThreeDigits pointer.

To use your operator as written, you must dereference `first` and `second`:

```
ThreeDigits* result = *first + *second;
```

This operator has an unusual signature though. `operator+` should return a ThreeDigits (i.e. not a pointer to one). It's extremely bad practice for your operator to implicitly new (or malloc) data because users will not expect this. RVO means that returning a copy isn't such a big deal anyway.

Comment: ... and if his class is just a wrapper around a `double` even copying it will be much faster than a heap allocation.

Comment: True. For some reason it escaped me that we are comparing the copy to a heap allocation, which is surely a more expensive operation in this case.